# What is the syntax for using a name attribute selector in a URL with parameters?

Tags: html, string, url

I'm trying to use a URL to drop down to a specific name attribute like so:

http://www.example.com/index.php#nameattribute

The jump works fine on its own but when I add a query string to the end of it, it will load the page but not jump down. It looks like this:

http://example.com/index.php#buy-it-now?utm_source=dummyINFO&utm_medium=dummy1&utm_content=dummyTwo&utm_campaign=Dummy2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fragment identifier must go **after** the query string.

The query string is the last part of the URL that is sent to the server. The fragment identifier species which part of the document the URL points to and is handled client side. It goes at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Query strings must go before the document fragment.

```
http://example.com/index.php?utm_source=dummyINFO&utm_medium=dummy1&utm_content=dummyTwo&utm_campaign=Dummy2015#buy-it-now
```

[As a related resource, there's a nicely designed "Link Anatomy" page that I often use for reference](http://bl.ocks.org/abernier/3070589).